Counting the number of instances of a value and returning it as a column in the result set
I have a table:



Owner_Name
Pet_type
Pet_Name




Fred
Dog
Scruffy


Fred
Dog
Rhino


Fred
Cat
Cuddles


Jan
Dog
Bones


Jan
Cat
Shadow


Michelle
Cat
Mario



How do I write the query that returns this:



Owner_name
Dog_Count
Cat_Count




Fred
2
1


Jan
1
1


Michelle
0
1



Here is what I have tried so far:
select Owner_name, Count(*) as dog_count 
from Pets 
where pet_type = 'Dog' 
group by owner_name

and
select Owner_name, Count(*) as cat_count 
from Pets 
where pet_type = 'Cat' 
group by owner_name

I have no idea how to make these into one query and have the count as a column in the same row. I need one row per pet owner.

Please update the question to include the SQL you've tried but did not work. Without that I am voting to close this question as it seems like a typical "I have a problem but haven't tried to solve it by myself yet"-Question.

Fair comment @MarkusSafar. I have updated now with what I have tried.

The solution in duplicate link works: https://sqlfiddle.com/oracle/online-compiler?id=33f268cc-a85e-4c87-a284-8c347e522710
